# Coupon code - cap amount on which a % discount applies

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, coupon

So I'm trying to setup a new coupon in Magento Shopping Cart Price Rules but I can't make it work as wanted. If you have any ideas, here's what it should do :

Coupon A should give 8% discount up to a 400€ cart value. So it's basically caped to 32€ BUT the customer should still be able to get the 32€ discount when his cart is above 400€.

Right now if I cap the cart value to 400€ then the coupon just becomes invalid when the cart value exceeds that amount.

Answer (score 0):

You have create one promotion rule for shopping cart price rule admin >> promotion >> shopping cart price rule

create new rule

in rule information tab view screen cast:http://prntscr.com/arpdxv

in condition tab set condition like below screen cast:http://prntscr.com/arp5fv

http://prntscr.com/arp6ew

in action tab you have to set values like in this screen cast:http://prntscr.com/arpeyr

set your label in label tab for rule:http://prntscr.com/arpfdc

after that click on save button to save rule

Comment: HI @pg-sutariya ! Thanks but this is not solving my problem. You gave me the rules to create a basic % discount.
What I want is that if the product price is above the cap then the rule still works but caps the discount to the fixed value of the coupon.